# Filter towns by state with regex (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let's say I have a list of towns, e.g. this one:

```
Ackworth, IA
Adel, IA
Afton, IA
Agency, IA
Ainsworth, IA
Albany, MO
Albia, IA
Aledo, IL
Alexandria, MO
Alleman, IA
Allendale, MO
Allerton, IA
Alma, MO
Altamont, MO
Altoona, IA
Amity, MO
Andalusia, IL
Ankeny, IA
Annada, MO
Arbela, MO
Arispe, IA
Armstrong, MO
Arrow Rock, MO
Ashburn, MO
Atalissa, IA
Atlanta, MO
Augusta, IL
Aullville, MO
```

And I only need to keep the towns belonging to MO state while getting rid of the others. Tried .+(?!MO)+\r\n - doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADd `.*` inside the negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*\bMO).+\r?\n?
```

or

```
^.+,\s+(?!MO).*\r?\n?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tT6hZ3/1)

Comment: Woops, it's not working exactly right. Some results from Iwova are still there. As for the second one - it's not working at all.

But with the regex from the link you provided everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
^\w+, (?!MO)[A-Z]{2}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tT6hZ3/3)

This asserts start of line, expects one or more word characters followed by a literal "comma space". It then asserts the next two characters are not MO, then matches any two capitals and asserts end of line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
(Sorry, I haven't an english version of N++, not sure to translate correctly).

- Go to menu `Search > Mark...`
- In the search input: `MO$`
- check `Mark all lines` and `Regular Expression`
- then click <kbd>Find All</kbd>
- Go to menu `Search > Signet (just before last entry)`
- Choose `Delete lines NON marked`